# Missing internal flash memory: It does not mount

Tags: internal-storage

I am using a [Xtouch X718](http://www.xtouch.ae/plus/view.php?aid=786) tablet. It is very nice: at the beginning I could do almost everything.

It used to be connected in computer and one day I was accessing it through the computer. Afterwards I took it out and opened the gallery -- but it did not open. When I looked at the settings it said "mount sd card in internal storage". I tried, but it did not mount.

Next time I accessed if from my computer it asked "disk" instead and showed the external sd card; as there is no external sd card it is not connected. It just goes as if in process for hours.